# Initializing Memcached/JDBC Resources for a JAX-RS servlet

Tags: java, design-patterns, jdbc, jersey, jax-rs

I have a service where I want to maintain data persistence in a mysql db using jdbc. While i have experience building jdbc apps and jax-rs apps in isolation, I've never combined the two. The question is, where does the build up and tear down required for the jdbc-type stuff go? Ordinarily i'd put the build up in a static block, or in a constructor, and id have have a cleanup method that gets called in a finally. this doesnt seem to work in the jax-rs framework- the constructor gets called at every invocation, and there is no place to my knowledge to put any clean up methods. unfortunately, there are sparse examples for combining the two technologies online, something i find surprising. Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, to do things at the startup and shutdown of your web application, you should create custom [ServletContextListeners](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and list them in your web.xml.

With JDBC resources in a WAR, often times you have your container (e.g. Tomcat, Websphere, etc.) create and manage a connection pool which can be shared with a number of web applications. You would define a `resource-ref` for a `javax.sql.DataSource` in your web.xml. Then  there is a container specific method for defining and binding the JDBC DataSource to the `resource-ref` of your application.

I'm not familiar with Memchached and what is needed on startup/shutdown so this is only a guess. If you need to register/unregister with a Memcache server you might try having one or more `env-entry` tags defined in your web.xml which could be used by a custom `ServletContextListener` to do your bidding.